# Method of second class doesn`t want to work in main class

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

guys! I have a problem. My method doesn`t want to work in main class Form1.
Closer to the point. I have main class Form1

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void GetLengthFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string result = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Input elem:");
            FirstArray.Text = result;

            // WHEN I CALL METHOD FROM MY CLASS Array IT DOESNT WORK
            Array _arr = new Array();
            _arr.Masstrickt(result);

            /* BUT WHEN I CALL PROPERTIES OF THIS CLASS FOR EXMPL
               ReturnSecond = "12345";
               IT WORK*/
        }

        public string ReturnSecond
        {
            get { return SecondArray.Text; }
            set { SecondArray.Text = value; }
        }
    }
```

Second class:

```
class Array
    {
        public void Masstrickt(string x)
        {
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            frm.ReturnSecond = x; 
        }
    }
```

Sorry for my grammar. I`m not native speaker

Comment: The `Form1 frm` in your `Array` class is not the real instance of your current `Form1`. You may change `void Masstrickt(string x)` to `string Masstrickt(string x)` and `ReturnSecond = _arr.Masstrickt(result);`

Comment: Okay, maybe you need to elaborate on "what doeesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass the result of `Masstrickt` to your form, so you need to change your function return type from `void` to `string`.

If you declare Array out of `Form1` class, set it to public

```
// public keyword would make Array visible to Form1 
public class Array
    {
        // Return type is string
        public string Masstrickt(string x)
        {
             return x;
        }
    }
```

In `Form1`

```
  public void GetLengthFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string result = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Input elem:");
            FirstArray.Text = result;

            Array _arr = new Array();
            ReturnSecond = _arr.Masstrickt(result);
            // ReturnSecond is the content of result 
        }
```